# Rust-SIMD hello world

Tags: rust, simd, rust-cargo

I couldn't find a working example for Rust-SIMD. The closest I can find is [this one](https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/%7Ecs146a/rust/rustbyexample-02-21-2015/simd.html). After adjusting, it becomes:

```
#![feature(core)]
#![feature(portable_simd)]

use std::simd::f32x4;

fn main() {
    let x = f32x4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

But still cargo complains

```
error[E0423]: expected function, found type alias `f32x4`
 --> src/main.rs:7:13
  |
7 |     let x = f32x4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  |             ^^^^^
  |
  = note: can't use a type alias as a constructor
```

during building.

How do I get this simple example working?

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "rust-simd"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
```

I have `nightly` switched on already: `rustup default nightly`.

Comment: Did you try searching on SO for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust+simd ?  There are some examples, some including https://godbolt.org/ links.  (But maybe not with full Cargo stuff.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to construct a SIMD vector with `std::simd` is `type::from(array)`, for example `f32x4::from([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])`. This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/simd/struct.Simd.html).

Comment: So the link I found expired?

Comment: @Rahn Probably. I haven't entered it. I would learn from official sources as much as possible.

Comment: @Rahn Considering your link is to some university professor's rip of Rust by Example and has "02-21-2015" in the url... I'd guess its very outdated